# This simple program freezes for no apparent reason

Tags: python, pygame

I've just started programming in Python. I've been reading the book called "Making Games with Python & Pygame" and it's been very helpful so far, but I cannot find the reason why this simple program freezes. It should display an image and then move it by pressing left or right. It's strange, since it was working properly --I didn't change anything. I have tried everything so I'd really appreciate your help! Thanks in advance!

```
import pygame, sys 
from pygame import *

# VARIABLES
x_res = 400
y_res = 300
DISPLAYSURF = 0
event = 0
person = 0
posx = 50
posy = 50

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((x_res, y_res))
pygame.display.set_caption("Test")

person = pygame.image.load("Person.png")

while True: # main game loop
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(person, (posx, posy))

    if event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_RIGHT:
            posx = posx + 5
            DISPLAYSURF.fill((0,0,0))
        if event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_LEFT:
            posx = posx - 5
            DISPLAYSURF.fill((0,0,0))
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYUP and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `for event in pygame.event.get()`?

Comment: ^ That is clearly the source of the problem. You should promote to answer.

Comment: This is one of the reasons `import *` is a terrible idea. Without the `import *`, this would have given you a clear error message instead of silently testing whether the `pygame.event` module was an element of `pygame.event.get()`.

Comment: I've never used pygame before, it's not so clear to me. I don't really know what's happening in this code, so I'll leave it to someone else to write up a nice answer.

Comment: @Rawing thanks so much! That "if" instead of "for" in the event.get loop was the cause. Also, thanks everybody! I really appreciate all your replies.

Comment: @Rawing that's the correct answer. There are a few more things that should be fixed, but they're not relevant to the problem. Actually, one problem is relevant, the variable `event = 0` hides the error in the `if event in pygame.event.get():` line. @MartinD you should rename that variable or remove it and also remove the star import `from pygame import *` which hides the error as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "freezing" in this case, but I guess the problem is because you don't have an image called `"Person.png"`, since when I tried out your code without an image on my file system called `"Person.png"` it also froze and gave me the error on the IDLE:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/your_program.py", line 17, in <module>
    person = pygame.image.load("Person.png")
pygame.error: Couldn't open Person.png
```

Instead, if I have an image called `"Person.png"`, it works properly.

Answer (score -4):

Try writing "(wilst) true" instead of while? :)

Comment: It's just a guess since they write "wilst" at https://www.pygame.org/lofi.html and say that they "spell colour without the u (sorry), and we always spell pygame with lower case letters."

Comment: The fact that the site uses the word "whilst" in its _text_ (incidentally, note the 'h') has no effect on the core syntax of Python.